# Function not giving a valid output (C on Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c, printf, calculator

I've tried to automate a calculus I do when working with electronics. Unfortunately, it seems like my code doesn't work as all results are 0.000000 (see below).

Here's what I've tried:
- variable in double or int
- removing the calculus part and try to get the outputs from the inputs
- scanf_s and scan_f.

Neither of these worked. What's strange is that the printf's at the end could not even print base_v (for example).

Here's the code itself:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // variable declaration
    double base_r, mod_r, base_v, mod_v=0;
    double coeff=1;
    int asdf=1;

    // welcome message
    printf("vMod calculator\n");
    printf("Please enter resistances in Ohms and voltages in Volts\n");

    // retrieve info about vmod
    printf("Enter base resistance\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &base_r);
    printf("Enter modified resistance\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &mod_r);
    printf("Enter base voltage\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &base_v);

    // calculus of modified voltage
    coeff=asdf*((1/base_r)+(1/mod_r));
    mod_v=base_v*base_r*coeff;


    // results
    printf("Base voltage: %f \n", &base_v);
    printf("Base resistance: %f \n", &base_r);
    printf("Modified voltage: %f \n", &mod_v);
    printf("Modified resistance: %f \n", &mod_r);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

In case you don't understand the calculus, please refer to the following image: http://pbrd.co/1g6KWLp

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the address of the `printf` arguments `&base_v` instead of its value `base_v`. In short, get rid of the `&`

```
printf("Base voltage: %f \n", base_v);
printf("Base resistance: %f \n", base_r);
printf("Modified voltage: %f \n", mod_v);
printf("Modified resistance: %f \n", mod_r);
```

Comment: I tried without the `&` and now I get four "-92559604647977569000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000".

Comment: I am not too familiar with the windows `scanf_s` but I know that `scanf` expects `%lf` as specifier for a double. Maybe you can try this either using floats or using `%lf` in your `scanf_s` calls

Answer (score 3):

Well to start with, you printing **pointers** as floating point numbers, and therefore have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` takes the variable directly, not its address:

```
printf("Base voltage: %f \n", base_v);
printf("Base resistance: %f \n", base_r);
printf("Modified voltage: %f \n", mod_v);
printf("Modified resistance: %f \n", mod_r);
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf leaves newline characters 0x13 and 0x10 in stdin buffer after first call, so next call gets 13/10 first, for dos/windows
Use fgets then fscanf or something like 
        while((dumchar=getch())==\n); 
to clear newlines before each scanf() call